# SSL Socket connection from Kubernetes pod to External Site

Tags: sockets, kubernetes, openssl, kubernetes-helm, k3s

I am learning k3s. Aa part of that:

1. I have created a k3s cluster with just one server node and zero Agent nodes.
2. Deployed my application using HELM scripts with no network polices in the server pod and want to invoke a SSL Socket connection. I ran below command and getting connection refused error.

   curl --include 
   --no-buffer 
   --header "Connection: Upgrade" 
   --header "Upgrade: websocket" 
   --header "Host: example.com:80" 
   --header "Origin: [http://example.com:80"](http://example.com:80%22) 
   --header "Sec-WebSocket-Key: SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==" 
   --header "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" 
   http://example.com:80/

Currently, I do not have any network policy setup for my k3s nodes which ideally should allow all traffic right?

Please let me know what should I do to make the SSL socket open and work.